# Find the answer of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find the answer of this limit
$$(a)\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{4}}2\cos{\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n-2}}-\sum_{k=\frac{n+3}{4}}^{ \frac{n-1}{2}}2\cos{\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n-2}}-\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{4}}2\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n+1}}+\sum_{k=\frac{n+3}{4}}^{ \frac{n-1}{2}}2\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n+1}}$$
By some computational softwares, I know
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{4}}2\cos{\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n-2}}-\sum_{k=\frac{n+3}{4}}^{ \frac{n-1}{2}}2\cos{\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n-2}}=\infty$$
And
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{4}}2\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n+1}}+\sum_{k=\frac{n+3}{4}}^{ \frac{n-1}{2}}2\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n+1}}=0$$
But based on some facts the answer of (a) can be $\frac{1}{2}$.